# Are gene conversions and expansion/contraction of repetitive (satellite) DNA examples of directional, non-random mutations?

Tags: genetics, dna, mutations

Are gene conversions and expansion/contraction of repetitive (satellite) DNA examples of directional, non-random mutations? For some context, it was brought to mind as a result of reading the following;

"Within the broad category of gene mutations we should consider not only the classical, purportedly random changes, but also the internally directed changes that are called gene conversion and duplicative transposition (collectively constituting molecular drive) (see Dover et al., 1981)." (From 'A Botanical Critique of Cladism', pp 14-15)

Comment: Please include your question in the question. A title is a title. This will also make you explain more fully and clearly.

Answer (score 1):

#### For Repetitive Sequences:

Duplications of repetitive DNA (as in replication-slippage) are not "as random" as radioactivity, but still, there is no genetic mechanism that intentionally triggers the duplication of a gene. Also, during replication slippage the site of DNA-pol re-association is random, causing duplications of different lengths. So I'd still call it a change that's both "random" (in terms of sequence) and "non directed" (as in "lacks a direct purpose").

**Together**, I'd prefer the term "***duplication***" over "mutation" for the expansion of repetitive/satellite DNA, (while "duplication" is a type of "mutation")

#### For Transposons:

Your reference cites 'duplicative transposition', and a lot of repetitive DNA originate from transposons ([Belyayev 2020](https://mobilednajournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13100-020-00219-7)). For jumping genes, I would prefer the term „***recombination***“ instead of "mutation".

The appearance/exchange of specific large sequences is called [Recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination).

From [Harret & Sherrat 1997](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/21/2/157/594254):

> In bacteria, two categories of specialised recombination promote a variety of DNA rearrangements. Transposition is the process by which genetic elements move between different locations of the genome, whereas site-specific recombination is a reaction in which DNA strands are broken and exchanged at precise positions of two target DNA loci to achieve determined biological function. **Both types of *recombination*** are represented by diverse genetic systems which generally encode their own recombination enzymes. These enzymes, generically called transposases and site-specific recombinases […].

Furthermore, so it‘s incorrect to categorize transposons as „non-random“, since they insert mostly at random sites and can cause random DNA-damage next to the excision/insertion site [Wicker et al. 2016](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27599761/).

> Indeed, the 3,000 bp flanking the excised transposons can contain over 10 times more mutations than the genome-wide average. Since DNA transposons preferably insert near genes, this is correlated with increases in mutation rates in coding sequences and regulatory regions.

In my eyes, a better example of "directed"/"intended" (but random in sense of sequence) mutagenesis would be [AID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation-induced_cytidine_deaminase), an enzyme that increases antibody binding variability by intentionally introducing point mutations at very **specific** and isolated sites inside one gene.

Comment: I can see how AID increases genome-wide mutation rates, but the individual mutations are still 'random' in the sense that there's no bias towards a specific sequence appearing at any site in the genome. On the other hand, it would appear to me that slippage at repetitive sites, and gene conversions (transpositions too though I didn't mention them), bias the appearances of specific sequences in the genome.

Comment: AID does not act genome wide. It‘s directed towards the variable region of immunoglobulin genes where it introduces random mutations in an isolated section in a controlled manner. You are mistaken, Transposons are not specific. They can even insert inside genes an inactivate them, and if too many transposons are active, they will destabilize the genome  (see piRNAs and infertility). In general, when talking about mutation, geneticists don‘t immediatley think about transposons. A far better term for large sequences changing location would be „recombination“

Comment: Understood for immunoglobin genes although the same point applies, the 'gene-wide' mutation rate doesn't bias the appearance of specific sequences or nucleotides (or does it?). I was not saying transposon insertion sites is non-random: what's non-random is the appearance of sequences specifically corresponding to the transposon sequence.

Comment: Yes, but the appearance of specific large sequences is better described with the term „recombination“ than with „mutation“. Yes, the term mutation is associated with transposons, BUT the mutation from transposon is due to random errors that come with sloppy deletion/integration of the transposon and subsequent DNA-repair (and not due to appearance of large specific sequences) [Wicker et al. 2016](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27599761/).

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to better describe it as recombination. What about expansion/contraction of repetitive DNA and gene conversions? Do you agree that this is directional mutation when it comes to appearance of specific sequences or do you think this is still, technically, random?

Comment: I'd say gene conversion is more recombination than mutation. I don't know about the expansion/contraction of repetitive DNA, isn't repetitive DNA just tons of inactive Transposons?

Comment: Not really. When repetitive DNA is being replicated, the nature of the repetitive region results in the slippage of the replication machinery, which can wind it backwards (thus re-replicating the same repeats, resulting in more repeats) or forwards (thus shortening the number of repeats). The actual repetitive sequences make it more likely that this kind of slippage happens during replication, thus biasing the appearance of more of the same repetitive DNA.

Comment: I see. This mechanism is not recombination then, obviously. I’d call this simply „(Gene) duplication“, when talking about this mechanism. Using the term „mutation“ isn‘t really incorrect, but still much to general or abstract compared to „Duplication“

Comment: Well ... i dont know if it's 'gene' duplication if you're not duplicating a gene, although short short repetitive sequences can be duplicated. From ScienceDirect: 'In replication slippage, a long stretch of repeat sequences in the DNA folds back and pairs on itself, forming an internal hairpin or stem–loop structure, during replication.' This seems to me to be a simple replication error, and therefore can be called a mutation. Of course you can be more specific in describing any kind of mutation.

Comment: Exactly, "mutation" is just too broad. It's good practice to specify the type of mutation, if you know it. If one says "cancer mutates" that can mean anything from chromosome breaks (aneuploidy) to point mutations. However, if one says "gene mutates", most people think that of (functional or non functional) point mutation(s).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139353/discussion-between-markur-and-arara).